# Bitmap returns empty when fetching image from google drive

Tags: android, bitmap

I am fetching image from google drive through storage access framework and convert it in to a bitmap. It's working fine in my galaxy A5 running on marshmallow but in my redmi 6A running on Oreo bitmap is returned empty. My code is as below

```
 uri = resultData.getData();
 isImageFromGoogleDrive = "com.google.android.apps.docs.storage".equals(Objects.requireNonNull(uri).getAuthority());

  if(isImageFromGoogleDrive){
  InputStream inputStream;
  try {
     inputStream = getBaseContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
     Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
```

the value of bm is empty on redmi 6A Oreo

Comment: you need to setup file provider for android 7 and above.

Comment: Can to do it any link for it

Comment: I am using storage access framework

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider

Comment: thank you. I will check

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == SELECT_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
            try (InputStream inputStream = sender.getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImageUri )) {
               Files.copy(inputStream, "your_path_here", StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
               Toast.makeText(sender, "A problem has occurred while importing image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               Log.e(TAG, "error copying files:" + ex.getMessage());
               return;
            }
        }
```

You can't just take the image like you would do with one image from SDCARD, so you need to copy that file in the memory (temporary or not) using Streams. This code will copy the image to a path, then you can do what you want with it.